# Reading an array in json-io: Object cannot be cast to List

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am using this library: https://github.com/jdereg/json-io

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do, to reproduce the error:

```
import com.cedarsoftware.util.io.JsonReader;

Map args = new HashMap();
args.put(JsonReader.USE_MAPS, true);
List<String> a = (List<String>)JsonReader.jsonToJava("[\"1.1\",\"1.2\"]", args);
```

Runtime, this throws:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class java.util.List ([Ljava.lang.Object; and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Alternatively, the `args` can be left out (delete the two middle lines and remove the `args` argument to `jsonToJava`) with the same effect.

Reading dictionaries/maps works fine, for example this code prints "example" as expected:

```
Map<String,Object> fields = (Map<String,Object>)JsonReader.jsonToJava("{\"example\":true}");
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> field : fields.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(field.getKey());
}
```

It's only arrays that I cannot figure out how to read. The documentation that I've been able to find for the library is rather terse and does not show an example of this. Tracing the source code to see what kind of object it should be, I end up in a function named readArray, where it uses an ArrayList internally: https://github.com/jdereg/json-io/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cedarsoftware/util/io/JsonParser.java#L280. It looks like what I'm doing should be castable to List (I've also tried ArrayList just to be sure).

Comment: The first string doesn't look like json, have you tried `"{\"array\": [\"1.1\",\"1.2\"]}"`?

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object;` is an array of `Object` so try casting to `Object[]` and handle the elements in the array individually. Why isn't it a `String[]` array? Because Json arrays can contain anything and the json parser doesn't know the type of the elements until all have been parsed (but it'd need store them somewhere while parsing so `Object` is the easiest to use type - a more sophisticated parser might check the type of all elements and build the result array accordingly but that's quite some effort for little return since you'd have to know the type and cast anyway).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I have, I removed the wrapping object for simplification. As far as I can tell, json.org does not say a JSON message has to start with a `{`. It also parses fine in nodejs with `JSON.parse(str)`. But I did try, because I was also not sure if it had to be wrapped, and it made no difference. If I replace the "true" value of the "example" element of the second code snippet, I get the same issue.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it tomorrow at work and report back.

Comment: @Thomas is right. `Object[]` array is returned. If you want to have control over deserialisation process and provide expected type use `Jackson` or `Gson` library.

Comment: @Thomas That works! Would you like to post it as an answer? I'm also not sure what exactly the difference is, especially because they seem to use ArrayList internally so from my understanding, even though the function returns an Object, it should be castable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class java.util.List

Note that `[Ljava.lang.Object` represents the array type for object arrays, so it is `Object[]`. Since json arrays can contain anything, i.e. strings, booleans, numbers, objects or arrays, and in any combination any JSON parser would have 3 options:

- Use `Object` as the array's element type. This would then result in `Object[]` as in your case.
- Use some array element type provided by the user, i.e. if you know the array will contain only strings then you'd tell the parser that it should produce a `String[]` result. If the array contains anything other than strings that would most likely fail though.
- A sophisticated parser might first collect the elements, determine their types and try to use the most special common types (if all elements are strings that would be `String`). However, the API can't reflect that because the compiler doesn't know what the json will contain at runtime. Hence the API could only use the first two options (an in many libraries like Jackon or Gson both are present) so the user would then have to cast either the array or the elements themselves and in that case there's little to be gained to make the parser that sophisticated.

Now you probably ask why the parser returns a `Object[]` instead of `List<Object>`. That's a decision made by the designer(s) of that library and I can only guess what the reasons are. However, json itself only knows arrays so the logical consequence would be to use Java arrays as well if no other type information is provided.

Comment: "*`[Ljava.lang.Object` represents the array type for object arrays*" To clarify, if it had just been an Object (non-array), the error would have contained `Ljava.lang.Object` without the `[`? That's how you could tell what the issue was?

Comment: @Luc the output (type) for `Object` would be `java.lang.Object`, the type for `String[]` would be `[Ljava.lang.String` - so `[L` indicates an array of the following type (in case of classes or interfaces). See here for some more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayComponents.html. Basically the output you get is defined by [`Class.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName())

Answer (score 1):

To extend the great answer of Thomas, here is a solution for human readable json:

Convert list of objects into json:

```
public String toJSONList(List<Foo> fooList) {
  Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
  args.put(JsonWriter.PRETTY_PRINT, true); // just to make sure it looks good
  args.put(JsonWriter.TYPE, false); //disable ugly @type properties
  return JsonWriter.objectToJson(fooList, args);
}
```

It generates nice human-readable json with list:

```
[
  {
    "id":100,
    "name":"John"
  },
  {
    "id":101,
    "name":"Tirion"
  }
]
```

Convert the above json back to List

```
public List<Foo> fromJSONList(String json) {
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put(JsonReader.USE_MAPS, true);

JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader();
List<Foo> result = new ArrayList<>();
Object[] array = (Object[])JsonReader.jsonToJava(json, args);
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  //we need to tell what is the type (remember that we have removed it above?)
  ((Map)array[i]).put("@type", "com.something.model.Foo");
  Foo foo =(Foo)jsonReader.jsonObjectsToJava((JsonObject) array[i]);
  result.add(foo);
}

return result;
}
```